# Can't edge scroll on Samsung RV510

Tags: touchpad, samsung

I installed Ubuntu on my Samsung RV510, and I have edge scrolling checked for my touchpad but it simply doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the twofingers scroll, but in my case the scroll wasn't very smooth and usually the page go up to top and down to bottom too fast when you scroll..

I found this to have a perfect and smooth (only vertical not horizontal) scroll:

- http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/index.php?topic=416075.0

Pratically you can load the mouse module like the way ubuntu 10.04 did with this:
(plug an external mouse becasue the touchpad will disconnect after the frist command..)

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

The two fingers scroll will work until the reboot, to have permanent change write:

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/options
```

then write on the file just opened:

```
options psmouse proto=imps
```

Save and reboot your pc..

This will load the psmouse module like ubuntu 10.04 
(this worked for me after loooong searches..)

But i don't know if this will fix edge scroll too..

Comment: Andrea, thank you so much for helping me with my laptop. Everything runs perfectly, and i owe it all to you!

Comment: I just saved to you the time i lost before! good karma.