# Samsung n150+ touchpad settings disappeared

Tags: touchpad, samsung, mouse-scroll

Edge scrolling wasn't working on my Samsung 150+ netbook so I enabled it using the fix described here:

[Can't edge scroll on Samsung RV510](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28212/cant-edge-scroll-on-samsung-rv510)

Since doing this the TouchPad options in System Settings have ceased to appear.

I really would like to  to disable the touchpad whilst typing but can no longer see the option to enable this. Is it possible to disable the touchpad whilst typing and have edge scrolling at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I am also using the same N150 netbook, there is a default shortcut on the keyboard for this netbook for enabling and disabling touchpad while typing.
It is

<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

It will disable the touchpad when you want while typing. I don't think there is any way to disable touchpad and still use the scrollbar as you have mentioned.